# Invisible objects with shadows not working as I intended

Tags: materials, objects, shadows

I want to create shadows with invisible objects. I have found one answered question about this topic and used it but my objects didn't go invisible they are just like that as you see on the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Is Camera Ray in your setup if you want the material to be invisible instead of Is Shadow Ray that makes the shadows invisible.

Comment: Coincidentally I just watched this video yesterday, this is without using nodes: https://youtu.be/5jtfz0row8M?t=2976

Comment: Note that object settings work per whole object, while using nodes you can do this per material so one object may have different parts. It depends on what you are after.

Comment: Good point, I didn't think of that since in the video it's applied to the entire object.